# python what is the import for threading?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I want to run some python code every 120 seconds.

I tried this:

```
class AppServerSvc :

    def f(self):
        # call f() again in 120 seconds
        spider = FantasySerieaSpider()
        settings = get_project_settings()
        crawler = Crawler(settings)
        crawler.signals.connect(reactor.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        crawler.configure()
        crawler.crawl(spider)
        crawler.start()
        log.start()
        reactor.run() # the script will block here until the spider_closed signal was sent
        threading.Timer(120, f).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
        AppServerSvc().f();
```

I got the `threading is not defined` error

This are my imports:

```
import pythoncom
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log, signals
from FantasySeriea.spiders.spider import FantasySerieaSpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from threading import Thread
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rather than (or in addition to?):

```
from threading import Thread
```

you want:

```
import threading
```

Comment: After using your code, I am getting `f` is not defined thought it is a function inside the class. I should that I have to say `self.f`, will try that

Comment: no, `self.f()` makes an infinity loop, what should I do please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli `self.f`, no `()` on the end.

Comment: could you check my new question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109713/scrapy-spider-sends-spider-close-signal-before-it-closes

Answer (score 5):

You're using `threading.Timer` in your code but you're importing only `Thread` from `threading` and putting it into the current namespace. What you want is to import the whole module:

```
import threading
```

If you are using `Thread`, make sure to replace `Thread` by `threading.Thread`. Also, you are in a class, so you need to add `self.` in prefix or `f` to refer the class member:

```
threading.Timer(120, self.f).start()
```